# How to use Microsoft's ios offline translation API?

Tags: ios, azure, translation, offline

If I find the offline translation of the ios system, I have not found any api about the azure ios offline translation on the official website.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently available for iOS. Seems like it was a feature that was available previously, but it is now limited. Their website doesn't include a section for iOS translation anymore.

I wish I could provide a valid source online but my information comes from several hours on customer service calls with Microsoft Representatives who either told me that (1) the feature doesn't exist, (2) the feature used to exist but they can't find the pages anymore, (3) that the feature never existed and that it will be coming soon to iOS.

Comment: I also contacted the customer service representative because my customer service representative is not a development team. He needs to contact me in the development project team of translate to determine the specific situation.